# IndexError at /password-reset/: string index out of range while resetting password

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a password reset feature using django's class based views. I have implemented all the recommended things in django but something just doesn't fits. Whenever i try to click on the send password reset email link button. It throws an string index out of range error.

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',User_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/',User_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/' , auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='Users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('', include ('blog.urls')),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and here is the settings.py file of my project -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK ='bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'Login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

this is my password-reset.html -

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Request Password Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is the error traceback-

```
> Internal Server Error: /password-reset/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 126, in _get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 124, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 68, in view
>     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 45, in _wrapper
>     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 142, in _wrapped_view
>     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py",
> line 220, in dispatch
>     return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 88, in dispatch
>     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py",
> line 142, in post
>     return self.form_valid(form)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py",
> line 233, in form_valid
>     form.save(**opts)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py",
> line 295, in save
>     email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py",
> line 250, in send_mail
>     email_message.send()   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py",
> line 291, in send
>     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py",
> line 110, in send_messages
>     sent = self._send(message)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py",
> line 122, in _send
>     from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, encoding)   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py",
> line 119, in sanitize_address
>     address = Address(nm, addr_spec=addr)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\headerregistry.py",
> line 42, in __init__
>     a_s, rest = parser.get_addr_spec(addr_spec)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\_header_value_parser.py",
> line 1582, in get_addr_spec
>     token, value = get_local_part(value)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\_header_value_parser.py",
> line 1394, in get_local_part
>     if value[0] in CFWS_LEADER: IndexError: string index out of range [24/Apr/2019 13:51:36] "POST /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 135700
> [24/Apr/2019 14:01:39] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5203 [24/Apr/2019
> 14:01:52] "GET /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4035 Internal Server
> Error: /password-reset/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 126, in _get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 124, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 68, in view
>     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 45, in _wrapper
>     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 142, in _wrapped_view
>     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py",
> line 220, in dispatch
>     return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 88, in dispatch
>     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py",
> line 142, in post
>     return self.form_valid(form)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py",
> line 233, in form_valid
>     form.save(**opts)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py",
> line 295, in save
>     email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py",
> line 250, in send_mail
>     email_message.send()   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py",
> line 291, in send
>     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py",
> line 110, in send_messages
>     sent = self._send(message)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py",
> line 122, in _send
>     from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, encoding)   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py",
> line 119, in sanitize_address
>     address = Address(nm, addr_spec=addr)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\headerregistry.py",
> line 42, in __init__
>     a_s, rest = parser.get_addr_spec(addr_spec)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\_header_value_parser.py",
> line 1582, in get_addr_spec
>     token, value = get_local_part(value)   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\_header_value_parser.py",
> line 1394, in get_local_part
>     if value[0] in CFWS_LEADER: IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Can you give an example of the type of email address that gives that error (e.g. non-ascii characters)?.

Comment: One possibility is that you are using an invalid `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` in your settings.

Comment: @Alasdair what's a proper setting for DEFAULT_FORM_EMAIL ? As you can see in my settings.py it's Email_HOST_USER...  ans there is no environment variable defined with this name ... is that what causing this error ?

Comment: You can hardcode `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'me@example.com'` or you can set an environment variable, but you must make sure that it is set to a valid email address. If you are using Gmail to send emails, then you need to use the account email address, because Google won't let you send mails from email addresses that you don't control.

Comment: and how to set password then ?

Comment: Again, you can hardcode the password in `settings.py`, or load it from an environment variable. The advantage of the environment variable is that you avoid committing secrets into your code repository. If you're getting `SMTPAuthenticationError` then this is a different problem to the original question so I can't help with that. If you search Stack Overflow for *django gmail*, there are many questions from users having problems. You might find it easier to use [`django-anymail`](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) with a transactional email provider like Amazon SES or Mailgun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused with your view here is my view for change password

```
class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
    extra_email_context = None
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    from_email = None
    html_email_template_name = None
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_form.html'
    title = ('Password reset')
    token_generator = default_token_generator

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        opts = {
            'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
            'token_generator': self.token_generator,
            'from_email': self.from_email,
            'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
            'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
            'request': self.request,
            'html_email_template_name': self.html_email_template_name,
            'extra_email_context': self.extra_email_context,
        }
        form.save(**opts)
        return super().form_valid(form)


INTERNAL_RESET_URL_TOKEN = 'set-password'
INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN = '_password_reset_token'
```

**`UPDATED :`**

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "youremail@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "<Your Passcode Here>"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**`you need do account access enabled`**

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I haven't manipulated or changed anything in  PassworResetView .. I just simply used it in the Urls.py as view... What can i do to change it ?

Comment: you need to set proper DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''default@gmail.com" like this

Comment: And do i have to set password(of my gmail account) too ?

Comment: I hardcoded the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL= "my valid email address". and now getting this error.

Comment: SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: After hardcoding host name and password ... this is what i'm getting - SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Comment: make sure that email is vaild and gmail's

Comment: Yes i,m using correct credentials. even my google activity got triggered and showed a warning. So i enabled less-secure apps but still not working

Comment: first, you need to unblock Recaptcha go with this link  and enable then your problem is solved :) https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I tried to run it again. Now this error coming and i'm getting more confures. Error - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: chill Don't worry we are dubugging line by line so don't be confused

Comment: you get this success message " Account access enabled "  after enabling re captcha https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: So far I have enabled less secure apps and unblocked recaptcha... Still getting the SMTPAuthenticationError- Username password not accepted

Comment: hey you import   `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: It worked. As for the first time it gave a security warning in account activity and automatically disabled less secure apps access. i had to enable them again. its working. thankyou so much for your time

Comment: Not an issue, greate